# How to make widget stick to top of keyboard

Tags: keyboard, flutter

I'd like to make a widget that sticks to the bottom of the page, and then is pinned to the top of the keyboard (when it appears).

Note how the input textfield is pinned to the keyboard in the image below:

[image: Chat app where TextField sticks to the keyboard]

How would I do this? I tried putting it in the `bottomNavigationBar`, but this (obviously) didn't work. Is there a builtin way to do this?

Comment: I don't have the code on hand. But i think you can do this by making a Scaffold. In the body of the scaffold you place a expanded. The childs of the expanded are your chat messages etc. And under the expanded you place the text box like in whats app. The expanded will  constantly expand to the end of your screen leaving enough room for a textbox if you place it under the expanded. If you can't figure it it i'll try it. Let me know!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use of bottomSheet option from Scaffold.

```
Scaffold(
    bottomSheet: chatBar(),
    body: Column(
           children: [
              Expanded(
               child: ListView()
              )
           ]
         )
    )
```

the chatBar is top of keyboard, when keyboard is open.

for transparent chatBar: can wrap Scaffold by

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    bottomSheetTheme: BottomSheetThemeData(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),  
  ),
```

Answer (score 20):

This is a working example of the thing you want. I think!
Just copy/paste/run

What's important in this example is the Expanded. A really nice widget that expands to as much space as it can get. And in result pushing the chat box down as much as possible
(Bottom of the screen or bottom of the keyboard)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: new ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
    }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
    final String title;

    @override
    _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
                title: new Text('49715760 Stackoverflow'),
            ),
            body: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                    new Expanded(
                        child: new Material(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            child: new Text("Filled"),
                        ),
                    ),
                    new Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: new TextField(
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'Chat message',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: android example?

Comment: This solution sadly is similar to the other in that it is not ideal as the TextField moves to its new position at a different speed to the keyboard, causing a less than ideal animation.

Comment: @hardanger do you have a solution for this then?

Answer (score 17):

## The best way to resolve this is to use a dedicated widget.

#### MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom will give you the value of the height covered by the system UI(in this case the keyboard).

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var home = MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page');
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: home,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _getBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getBody() {
    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/sample.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.fitWidth)),
        // color: Color.fromARGB(50, 200, 50, 20),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[TextField()],
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          child: Text("Hiiiii"),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.pink),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Using Positioned + MediaQuery nailed it :)

Comment: This is a nice clean solution, however not ideal as the TextField moves to its new position at a different speed to the keyboard, causing a less than ideal animation.

Comment: Simple and clean solution!

Comment: just some info, it turns out that wrapping a widget in function is not a good practice in flutter cause it will always be rendered (if stateful) even if the context is exactly the same. so the  best approach is to extract it to flutter actual widget,
so instead of getBody()
just build a widget HomepageBody or something similar.

some readable article https://dartcodemetrics.dev/docs/rules/flutter/avoid-returning-widgets

Answer (score 5):

there is a lib for that:

https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_attachable

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) => FooterLayout(
    footer: MyFooterWidget(),
    child: PageMainContent(),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 Padding(
      padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom*0.04), //modify 0.04 to what suits you
      child: TheEntireWidgetYouWantToWrap(child: ...) 
 )
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
showBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Container(
  height: // YOUR WIDGET HEIGHT
  child: // YOUR CHILD
)
```

showBottomSheet is a flutter inbuilt function.