# How to move AppBar when Keyboard is opened?

Tags: flutter

So my app looks like this:

[image: App Image]

Now, when I click the TextField in the BottomAppBar, I see this:

[image: bottom app bar hidden]

Code:

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue[50],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
    child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Add a new item'),
        onSubmitted: (str) => {},
    )),
```

I want the BottomAppBar to move up when I type so I can see what I'm typing. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: maybe helpful for you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715760/how-to-make-widget-stick-to-top-of-keyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally suggest not using the bottomnavigationbar, which is meant to disappear under a keyboard, but instead just use a bottom-aligned view in the `body` of your scaffold. This will automatically move up when the keyboard appears. If you put the `ListView` and the `Container` with the textfield into a column and wrap the `ListView` in an `Expanded` widget, it should work pretty easily:

```dart
Column(
    children: [
        Expanded(child: ListView(...)), // your item list
        Container(...), // your textfield
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `Container` in the `bottomNavigationBar` property:

```dart
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
          ),
```

Or to keep the padding you already added:

```dart
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
          ).add(
            const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          ),
```

[image: Screenshot of example]

Answer (score 2):

You should try with stack

```
Stack(
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          ---------
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue[50],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Add a new item'),
                onSubmitted: (str) => {},
              )),
        ),

      ],
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

What @fravolt suggested is right in the sense that bottomnavigationbar should not move as per Material Design.
In my case I moved the widget up using the `Translate` widget:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);

    Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset(
        0.0,
        -1 * mediaQueryData.viewInsets.bottom,
      ),
      child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue[50],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
    child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Add a new item'),
        onSubmitted: (str) => {},
    )),

}
```