# Why does my widget get squished when the keyboard appears?

Tags: android, flutter, widget

The chatScreen holds the receivedChats (top) and the msgInput (bottom) widgets. For some reason, the words "Write message..." go outside of their text input widget and I'm not sure why.

**chatScreen:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final groupIDPath = 'groupChats/path'; 
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Group Chat Screen'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(102, 204, 125, 1.0),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Column( 
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 8,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ReceivedChats(groupIDPath: groupIDPath),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: MsgInput(groupIDPath: groupIDPath),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
```

**receivedChats:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final messageDao = MessageDao(groupIDPath: widget.groupIDPath);
    var msg;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data?.length ?? 0,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            data?.forEach((key, value) {
              msg = Message.fromJson(value);
              dataList?.add(msg);
            });
            if (dataList?[index] == null) { 
              return Text('');
            } else {
              return messageDao.messageWidget(dataList?[index].type, dataList?[index].uid, dataList?[index].text);
            }
          }
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

**msgInput:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: Container(color: Colors.blue,)
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 10,
                    child: TextField(
                        controller: messageController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Write message...",
                        )
                    )
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                    child: Container(color: Colors.green,)
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `Scaffold body` with `SingleChildScrollView`, i think its better to use in `chatScreen`:

```
return Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ...
    ),
);
```

or give `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false` to `Scaffold` to avoid this problem

read about [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

Comment: Neither option worked. For the first, all I see now is a completely white screen with no app bar and a bunch of errors in Android Studio: `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded`, `RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#8a3f9 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE`, ... For the 2nd option, when I click to begin typing something the entire bottom section (msgInput) disappears and all I see is the white background of the receivedChats widget. When I close the keyboard, the bottom section reappears.

Comment: wrap your column with `Expanded` too, i think its better to wrap your widgets or part of into `Container` which change the width and heigth due to device by `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`,

Comment: I wrapped with expanded, then tried either the scroll view or the resize property or both and it didn't work. Errors are `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget`, `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded`, ...

Comment: Maybe the way I am trying to do this is all wrong. Is there a more standard way to do a chat header (output) and chat footer (input)?

Comment: i think so, if need chat footer, this question is maybe better for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715760/how-to-make-widget-stick-to-top-of-keyboard but unfortunately i dont know if there is a specific and standard way to do that

Comment: i think https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_attachable is good solution for you too