# How to position a widget on top of the keyboard when it opens in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app where I want to position a specific widget, such as a comment input field and send button, on top of the keyboard when it opens. the goal is to duplicate a TikTok's comment implementation.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
onTap: () {
                Get.bottomSheet(Container(
                  height: height * 0.7,
                  width: width,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                      )),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                  "${widget.video["commentsCount"]} comments"))),
                      Expanded(flex: 5, child: Text("BODY")),
                      Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: iconSize,
                              width: iconSize,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(widget.video['user']
                                              ['profilePic'] ==
                                          ""
                                      ? 'https://picsum.photos/id/1062/400/400'
                                      : widget.video['user']['profilePic']),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: width * 0.02,
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: height * 0.015),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: width * 0.03),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.grey[100],
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      const Expanded(
                                          child: Center(
                                        child: TextField(
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.transparent),
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            border: InputBorder.none,
                                            hintText: "Add comments...",
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                      IconButton(
                                          onPressed: () {},
                                          icon: Icon(
                                            Icons.send,
                                            color: Colors.tealAccent,
                                          ))
                                    ],
                                  )),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ));
              },
```

I want the last Expanded widget to be positioned on top of the keyboard rather than at the bottom of the screen. Could someone please provide guidance or code examples on how to achieve this effect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use of bottomSheet option from Scaffold.

```
Scaffold(
    bottomSheet: chatBar(),
    body: Column(
           children: [
              Expanded(
               child: ListView()
              )
           ]
         )
    )
```

the chatBar is top of keyboard, when keyboard is open.

more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715760/how-to-make-widget-stick-to-top-of-keyboard)